# How to draw dotted line or line in google map in asp.net based on latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, asp.net, google-maps, html

I want to show the foot path (connected line of  location) in Google map using longitude and latitude of GPS data to track the location path in asp.net or PHP.

I am having my longitude and latitude data in stored/pulled from Mysql table like follows:

```
--------------------
|longitude | latitude|
----------------------
|10.000    |74.7444|
|10.000    |74.7444|
|10.000    |74.7444|
|10.000    |74.7444|
|10.000    |74.7444|
|10.000    |74.7444|
--------------------
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes - a polyline maybe is what you are wanting?? At any rate, the Google Maps api documentation is extensive. More than enough info show you what you need.

Comment: `Google Maps Directions API` is what you need but it has limit for per day usage. If need limitless you have to set-up an account with google and then subscribe a package.

Comment: it working but if i zoom the map the line hided or not showing....